# How can I use PyPy as standard/default interpreter in PyCharm 4.5.2?

Tags: python, pycharm, pypy

How can I use PyPy as standard/default interpreter in PyCharm 4.5.2?
Everything runs under Ubunutu 14.10 and pypy is already installed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You configure this under the settings for the project.  [This is directly covered by the official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

In case that link fails to open, go to the 'settings', then the 'project pane', and then select your desired interpreter from the drop down.  If it's not listed in that window, click the cog, then add 'add local', and navigate to the interpreter you desire.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. As I accustomed to use Eclipse, I was a little bit lost when searching the project settings. Starting in the PyCharm's main window the complete click path is: _File -> Settings -> Project: <project name> -> Project Interpreter_

Comment: When using pypy as the interpreter, does debugging work?